# How to set cm:title via camel-cmis?

Tags: java, apache-camel, alfresco, cmis

i have to set the Alfresco cm:title property using Apache Camel integration framework. 
The document is imported correctly in Alfresco but without the cm:title.

I tried to set the aspect cm:titled and after the cm:title property but doesn't work.

My processor method:

```java
List<String> secondary = new ArrayList<String>();
secondary.add("P:cm:titled");
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(PropertyIds.CONTENT_STREAM_MIME_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(PropertyIds.NAME, exchange.getIn().getHeader("file_name"));
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(CamelCMISConstants.CMIS_FOLDER_PATH, "/Sites/test/documentLibrary/demo");
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, CamelCMISConstants.CMIS_DOCUMENT);
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(PropertyIds.SECONDARY_OBJECT_TYPE_IDS, secondary);
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put("cm:title", exchange.getIn().getHeader("year"));
```

Any solution?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Camel, so I'm trying to guess here. I'm guessing the "name" is correctly set; how does your "PropertyIds.NAME" look like, does it have prefix like "cm" or does it have the full namespace?

Comment: The "PropertyIds.NAME" is "cmis:name"

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this cmis connection:

```java
 from("jms:importer")
                .process(executeFirstProcessor())
                .to("cmis://http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/cmis/versions/1.1/atom?username={username}&password={password}")
                .end();
```

Instead of:

```java
 from("jms:importer")
                .process(executeFirstProcessor())
                .to("cmis://http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom?username={username}&password={password}")
                .end();
```